# Elastic search java aggregation api on ES side

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aggregation

Here is [refer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/2.3/_bucket_aggregations.html#java-aggs-bucket-global) I'm looking at. I'm wonder why aggregation works on client side.
Whatever type of aggregation, It has same step.

- get bucket data to client side
- with raw data, aggregating on CLIENT SIDE.

If data size is getting bigger, it may need much more time and resource to aggregate data on client side than ES side.

Why are they designed like this way? There is no way to aggregate data on ES side with java api?

Comment: Where do you see that it should be on client side?

Comment: In refer link, It commented "sr is here your SearchResponse object", and aggregate sr object.

Comment: Ah, I see :) You misunderstood something. The documentation is about how you can access the result of the aggregation. The aggregation are done on the server side: You can see [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/query/QueryPhase.java#L136) that the aggregations are executed within the QueryPhase on the server. ;)

Comment: Sorry, It was my misunderstood. solved it :)